# how to increment a variable insidet s:iterator tag

Tags: struts2

I have an s:iterator tag like the following

```
<s:iterator value="results">
    <s:property value="someIntValue"/>
</s:iterator>
```

At the end of this loop i want the total of someIntValue. In plain java I would do something like this

```
variable += someIntValue
```

but can this be done inside the struts2 tag?  I looked at documentation for [s:set](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/set.html) tag but was not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

```
<s:iterator value="users" status="itStatus">
    <li>
       <s:property value="#itStatus.count" />
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```

Count should give you the value you are looking for. More detail:
[link text](http://www.opensymphony.com/webwork/api/com/opensymphony/webwork/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html)

From struts in action book:

Sometimes it’s desirable to know status information about the iteration that’s taking
place. This is where the status attribute steps in. The status attribute, when defined,
provides an IteratorStatus object available in the ActionContext that can provide
simple information such as the size, current index, and whether the current
object is in the even or odd index in the
list. The IteratorStatus object can be
accessed through the name given to the
status attribute.

Comment: that is not what I was asking. I am not concerned with the 'iteration number'.  I am more concerned with the value coming from getSomeIntValue in the action class.  Every iteration this value might be different and I want to count all those values. for example for 3 iterations value for someIntValue is: iter1->10, iter2->20, iter3->30. then at the end I want total which would be 60.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you:

```
<% int variable = 0 %>

<s:iterator value="results">
    <s:property value="someIntValue" var="number"/>
    <% variable += ${number} %>
</s:iterator>

<%= variable %>
```